# How to get intern to not stare at me during the day?

Tags: work-environment, internship, relationships

I work at a relatively small company (55 employees) and we are basically a bunch of guys developing software at our R&D sector.

Recently, we hired a new intern to help with organizing a lot of documents. She is new to the work environment and keeps slacking off all the time, staring at me creepily and looking away every time I make any movements.

How can I politely resolve this situation?

Comment: You seem to have a negative opinion of this person- other than this specific complaint, is there anything else that's bothering you? Why do you say that she is slacking off? And more importantly, why did your company hire an intern to solve its management issues?

Comment: Nah. I'm on a good mood. But how could you have a good impression of a person who stays staring at you half of the working hours? The company has decided to hire an intern to organize a lot of documents, it's a common practice in my country because is a cheap way to go.

Comment: Why do you say that she is slacking off? And while we're at it, why is Berta a more apt pseudonym than, say, Jane?

Comment: Welcome to the site Holmes. I've taken the liberty of editing your post based on your comment and tried to make it a bit more neutral. That said, I'm still not sure what to make of you identifying her staring as being "creepy" so perhaps you could clarify that further.

Comment: She isn't designed to do a lot of tasks everyday, it's a very simple job. Once she run away of her duties, we can always see that she is slacking off. There's no harm on the past provided name, it was a good fit just because it starts with 'B'.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are extenuating circumstances that make it difficult for you to walk over and politely tell her that her actions make you uncomfortable. If not, this is a clear duplicate question and should be closed.

Comment: @PatrickN I fully approve of the name "Jane" :D

Answer (score 16):

I voted to close this question because I don't think it's a real question, but I'll throw an opinion out there just for the sake of getting down-voted with vigor.

The proper way to deal with it is to ["man up"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man_up). Take responsibility for yourself, walk over, introduce yourself and discuss it with her. This is not rocket science, it is not even a question. It's a matter of simple human relations. What would you do if a friend of yours was doing it at a dinner table? A brother/sister from across the room?

She's not the crazy guy on the subway who might have a knife and you want to avoid all eye contact. She's a human being, and someone felt she was adult enough to be hired. So it stands to reason that she's adult enough to be treated like one.

So go be an adult and resolve it.

Comment: *"Any discomfort with a coworker should be known and understood because it affects your productivity. You'll think about it all the time and when the guy comes back after a break or something you'll start being nervous again."*

Comment: @Holmes: Yes, I recall that question and answer. However, if you walk over and behave like an adult, treat this person with respect, I'm sure you'll quite easily overcome any discomfort. Oh, and btw, cite your references if you're going to quote someone.

Comment: @Jack: Truly. However, it crossed my mind wondering how OP knew this person was staring at him if he wasn't also ogling her. Perhaps she's staring because she thinks he's a creep and feels uncomfortable around him.

Comment: @Jack: No, I'm not victimizing either of them. I'm simply posing the questions. I think quite honestly my answer is that OP should be an adult and deal with this person 1 on 1 to alleviate any discomfort. If there is true "stalkerish behavior" as you suggest in one of your comments, then OP should do what anyone should do in that situation, report it to HR and, if it's dangerous, the police.

Comment: I actually agree with the point to what you are saying but the language you are using seems.. intentionally confrontational?

Comment: @enderland: I can accept that criticism. I find this inability of people simply to deal with each other directly while having no difficulty complaining about it on the Internet troubling.